# sharepoint list relationship question

Tags: sharepoint, list, designer, lookup, relationship

I have two custom lists in sharepoint with a one to many relationship on a column in both lists.  So list A has text column 1 and list B has a lookup column 1' on list A's column 1.  I want to display the rows in list A, where column 1 has a match on column 1' and a 2nd column in list B with a specific text string.  I have Sharepoint Designer and am fumbling along with linked sources described here http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA100991441033.aspx, but can't get exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that there is no real concept of relationships in MOSS 2007.  This does, however, become a concept known to SP2010.  The route that you would want to take to achieve something similar would be a custom programming solution.  Anything you do with Designer will work, but it won't provide you with the flexibility that you are probably needing in maintainability and reuse.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a developer and have site collection access to the server, you should check out [SLAM](http://slam.codeplex.com), a codeplex project my company built that will allow you to do exactly what you are looking for.